# Where to find the Catalog's predispatch event handler for sanitization?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

Let's say we have a list of wrenches:

https://www.toolworld.com/hand-tools/wrenches?order=price

I'm trying to find the **predispatch event handler** for the Catalog's product list page so that I can sanitize the '**order**' parameter's input before it is sent to the controller.

I'm new to magento and have been having trouble finding it.

Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** After some digging I found that there wasn't a predispatch handler already defined in my config.xml file for the page I cited (Catalog Category View) so I had to create one.

**Longer answer:** I consulted '*Phparchitect's Guide to E-Commerce Programming with Magento*' which has a section that lists the syntax of predispatch events you can listen for, namely:

```
controller_action_predispatch

controller_action_predispatch_ModuleName

controller_action_predispatch_ModuleName_ControllerName_ActionName
```

I plugged in my module, controller, and action names (Catalog/Category/View) and created a new handle in config.xml, which also specified an Obserfer class and a method like so:

```
<controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view>
    <observers>
        <template>
            <class>Template_Catalog_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>predispatchCatalogCategoryView</method>
        </template>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view>
```

Afterward, I navigated to the Observer class and created a new method with the method name specified above. Using my debug log I was able to detect this method being hit upon loading the page again.